# FILESYSTEMEXCEPTION , Invalid depfile in flutter

Tags: flutter

so i'm following a tutorial and trying to build an app with cards in it that has a quote , i've put the quotes in a list as objects from a class named quote , and made a function that returns a card , everything was working fine , but suddenly these weird errors started to face me
this is the  code

```
 import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'quote.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => Myappstate();
}

class Myappstate extends State<MyApp> {
  List<quote> quotes = [
    quote(text: 'be alive , not a survivor', author: 'mark'),
    quote(
        text: 'we are more humilated when we are afraid of being humilated',
        author: 'tom'),
    quote(text: 'shut up , and do the work ', author: 'isaak')
  ];
  Widget Quotethecard(quote) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Text(quote.text),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 6,
                    ),
                    Text(quote.author)
                  ],
                ))));
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('LIFE QUOTES'),
              //   centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
            body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: quotes.map((quote) => Quotethecard(quote)).toList(),
            )));
  }
}
```

and these are the errors :

```
Invalid depfile: C:\flutter projects\flutter app2\flutter_application_2\.dart_tool\flutter_build\fa97722b3b47c4f49ae962e1d74ff742\kernel_snapshot.d
: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
lib/main.dart:1
import 'dart:html';
       ^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
   StandardFileSystem.entityForUri 
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:614:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:754:21)

<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:571:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

#4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:85:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to delete `import 'dart:html';` and run the project again.